# Error: No version of chokidar is available. Tried chokidar@2 and chokidar@3

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My `react js` project suddenly I have faced a problem when I try to `npm start` then show me error like this:

```
C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\watchpack\lib\chokidar.js:17        
throw new Error(
^

Error: No version of chokidar is available. Tried chokidar@2 and chokidar@3.
You could try to manually install any chokidar version.
chokidar@3: Error: Cannot find module 'chokidar'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\watchpack\lib\chokidar.js
- C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\watchpack\lib\DirectoryWatcher.js 
- C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\watchpack\lib\watcherManager.js   
- C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\watchpack\lib\watchpack.js        
- C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\node\NodeWatchFileSystem.js
- C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\node\NodeEnvironmentPlugin.js
- C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js    
chokidar@2: Error: Cannot find module 'watchpack-chokidar2'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\watchpack\lib\chokidar.js
- C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\watchpack\lib\DirectoryWatcher.js 
- C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\watchpack\lib\watcherManager.js   
- C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\watchpack\lib\watchpack.js        
- C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\node\NodeWatchFileSystem.js
- C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\node\NodeEnvironmentPlugin.js
- C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\mern stack\client\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
```

I don't know what does mean

Any suggestion Please.